# Why No XM From Ingress Portal

Tags: ingress

In the game Ingress, in my neighborhood, there is a newish Portal that went online last week.  Control of it has passed back and forth between factions a few times, and it's been used by at least one side to create multiple Links and Fields, but to date, it hasn't provided any XM.  I've checked many times, at all times of day.  I'm sure that the issue isn't that other players are grabbing all the XM before I get a chance to see it.  I've confirmed with other players that it doesn't provide them any XM, also.  I haven't run across any other Portals that don't provide XM.  Does anybody happen to know...

Why would an Ingress Portal not provide XM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is listed as a "known issue" on Google's [Ingress help pages](http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2884602?hl=en&ref_topic=2799232). That states "It may take up to two weeks for XM to begin to spawn around new Portals."

Answer (score 3):

XM appears to be controlled by a separate database.
Updating that with new portal locations takes time; up to a week has been observed.

Answer (score 2):

Last time new portals appeared, it take a few days to see them produce XM.

They start producing XM about 48 hours after their first capture.

EDIT: the one from the last batch still no produce XM :(

Another EDIT : Try to contact the [ingress support](http://support.google.com/ingress) -> Contact us -> Problem with a portal, maybe it is a bug.